# Is there a way to see "view pull request" also after a push in a github repository (like bitbucket)?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Whenever you open a pull request and push un update in its branch, bitbucket shows in the response the link to view the pull request. It is very nice feature. I click there and run into the browser to see the diff between my branch and develop. I do not use graphic tools to compare that two branches. I like compare via browser.

Comment: The pull request automatically will be updated after the push.

Comment: I know, ... I am asking if there is a common way to see in the terminal the link to github.

Answer (score 0):

No,  not in general.

The link is outputted via a post receive hook in the server side.